# mmm mmmmmmmmm mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm mmmmmmmm mmmmm mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm mmmmmmmmm mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm

Tags: cipher, english, computer-puzzle

mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm mmmmmmmmmmmm mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm mmmmm mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm mmmmmmmm mmmmmmmmm mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm mmm mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm mmmmmmmmm mmm

mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm mmmmmmmm m mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm mmmmmmmmm mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm mmmmmmmm mmmmm mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm mmmmmmmm mmmmmmmmm mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm mmmmm mmmmm mmmmmmmmmmmmmm mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm mmmmmmmm mmmmmmmmmmmm mmmmm mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm mmmmm mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm mmmmmm mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm mmmmmmmm mmmmm mmmmm mmmmmmmmmmmmmm mmmmmmm mmmmmmmmmmmm mmmmmmmmm mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm mmmmmmmm m mmmmmmmmmmmm mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm mmmmmmmm m mm mmmmm mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm

Hint:

> See tags

Comment: see the tags before downvoting

Comment: I think it is a seriously created puzzle, but I feel that the title should not be encrypted like that. Instead it should give a brief description of the contents. I upvoted to support the question, but also would suggest an edit.

Comment: Even knowing that it is intended as a puzzle, I've still downvoted. It is very low-effort (using one of the simplest encodings possible), and comes across as spammy; neither is something I want to encourage on PSE.

Comment: +1 It was fun to solve.

Comment: @Deusovi You still kind of encouraged it by answering it ...

Comment: why did you bounty this?

Comment: @Ankit , already mentioned ..at top  "i am rich, giving away my points"..

Comment: "*i am rich, giving away my points*"; to whom? Both answers are provided by users that are "richer" than you are. It's like donating your money to [Jeff Bezos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeff_Bezos).

Comment: @Tacoタコスok,, just feeling rich in my mind donating by points..as i am not so rich to donate money... :(

Comment: @Ankit, enjoy!!

Comment: Wow. I wonder why your post was downvoted so much on day one!

Comment: Any reason for downvotes? @riskymysteries

Comment: @AmruthA Huh? I upvoted... 1 year and 5 months ago.

Comment: Sorry if it seemed like otherwise, but I meant to compliment your post.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here is how I solved it:

First, find the length of each string of `m`s:

```
s = '''mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm mmmmmmmmmmmm mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm mmmmm mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm mmmmmmmm mmmmmmmmm mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm mmm mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm mmmmmmmmm mmm

mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm mmmmmmmm m mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm mmmmmmmmm mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm mmmmmmmm mmmmm mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm mmmmmmmm mmmmmmmmm mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm mmmmm mmmmm mmmmmmmmmmmmmm mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm mmmmmmmm mmmmmmmmmmmm mmmmm mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm mmmmm mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm mmmmmm mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm mmmmmmmm mmmmm mmmmm mmmmmmmmmmmmmm mmmmmmm mmmmmmmmmmmm mmmmmmmmm mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm mmmmmmmm m mmmmmmmmmmmm mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm mmmmmmmm m mm mmmmm mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm 
'''
print(' '.join(map(str, map(len, s.split()))))
```

Output:

```
19 15 12 22 5 20 8 9 19 3 18 25 16 20 9 3 23 8 1 20 9 19 20 8 5 20 8 9 18 20 5 5 14 20 8 12 5 20 20 5 18 15 6 20 8 5 5 14 7 12 9 19 8 1 12 16 8 1 2 5 20
```

Then find the letter form for each number using `chr`:

```
s = '19 15 12 22 5 20 8 9 19 3 18 25 16 20 9 3 23 8 1 20 9 19 20 8 5 20 8 9 18 20 5 5 14 20 8 12 5 20 20 5 18 15 6 20 8 5 5 14 7 12 9 19 8 1 12 16 8 1 2 5 20'

print(' '.join(chr(int(m)+96) for m in s.split()))
```

Output:

> `s o l v e t h i s c r y p t i c w h a t i s t h e t h i r t e e n t h l e t t e r o f t h e e n g l i s h a l p h a b e t`

> `solve this cryptic what is the thirteenth letter of the english alphabet`

Answer:

> `m`

Comment: *Smirks in Palpatine*

Answer (score 14):

Heavy credits to the other two answers.

Everyone keeps saying the answer is

> m

However, I disagree because:

> it should be answered in the same language it was posted.

Hence, the answer is:

> mmmmmmmmmmmmm

Yes, I know that this is ridiculous, but this bounty being there is honestly super annoying, so i'm posting this so it goes away.

Comment: +100 for creativity..

Answer (score 9):

This is encoding a message in a very simple way:

> Take 1 `m` to be "a", 2 `m`s to be "b", 3 `m`s to be "c", and so on. It then spells [with capitalization, punctuation, and spacing added by me]:
>
>  "Solve this cryptic puv. What is the thirteenth letter of the English alphabet?"
>  Presumably "puv" is supposed to be "puzzle". The answer to the question is the letter m.

Answer (score 6):

Props to those who have come before me, but another possible answer is

> The letter p

because the puzzle's text decrypts to

> "solve this cryptic what is the thirteenth letter of the english alphabet"

And the 13th letter of

> "the english alphabet" is p

Comment: rot13(Lrnu! Bgurejvfr abg zhpu bs n 'pelcgvp', vf vg?)